# How to set a method that is called only when the app is closed?

Tags: java, android

I want to call a method when the app is closed. I looked up some of the similar questions and I found 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744933/android-ondestroy-isnt-called-when-i-close-the-app-from-the-recent-apps-button) . But the question's answer doesn't work for me. (Error didn't occur but doesn't work)
Some people refer to `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` but I want to call a method only when closing the app, not when closing an Activity. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

one way is to get a list of running activities in onDestroy() of activities (or services) and call the method if there are no other activities running.